# xampp htdocs is readonly and can't remove read only attribute

Tags: windows, xampp, readonly

I have install xampp in my windows 7.
It's htdocs folders gone read only. And when try to remove it I can't.
I have tried both gui and cmd commands for unset read only attribute but it restore after changing. what shoul I do?
My images not shown in my local websites because of lack of permission.
here is chrome image for showing image:

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/pkhodro/web/img/brands/29ba0808a95e9497aef33b4da8fb9cbc.jpg`